# marker.setVisible is not a function in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My map shows the points from the json, but I can not filter these points with the code below. I think there should be a connection between the markers and the filter, but I don't know how.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 8
});

var points = 'http://www.example.com/json.json';

$.getJSON(points, function(json1) {
    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latlng.lat, data.latlng.lng); 
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            category: data.category,
            //icon: iconBase + data.posture + '.svg',
            title: data.title
        });
    });

    filterMarkers = function (posture) {
        for (i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
            marker = json1[i];
            // If is same category or category not picked
            if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            // Categories don't match 
            else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
    $('.button-group a').click( function(e){
        var category = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        filterMarkers(category);
    });

});
```

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: What is the error ? What steps have you tried to solve the problem ?

Comment: When I try to click on a filter anchor (`.button-group a`) the console return an error `marker.setVisible is not a function`

Comment: the `marker` that you do `marker.setVisible()` on needs to be the google marker itself. It looks like you are trying to perform the function on one of your json elements `json1[i]`. You'll need to store the google markers in an array when you create them and then access the correct array item when you want to run the function.

Comment: When you create your marker, you don't keep track of it, juste create it in the `$.each` scope. Then when you write `marker = json1[i]`, marker is most likely not a Marker object

Comment: Ok so how can I make my markers "real" markers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understood the comments below. To do this, I put all the markers in an array and my filter acts on this array

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 8
});

var points = 'http://www.example.com/json.json';

$.getJSON(points, function(json1) {
    var markers_array = [];
    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latlng.lat, data.latlng.lng); 
        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            category: data.category,
            //icon: iconBase + data.posture + '.svg',
            title: data.title
        });

        markers_array.push(marker);

    });

    filterMarkers = function (posture) {
        for (i = 0; i < markers_array.length; i++) {
            marker = markers_array[i];
            // If is same category or category not picked
            if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            // Categories don't match 
            else {
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
    $('.button-group a').click( function(e){
        var category = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        filterMarkers(category);
    });
});
```